# merge file on the basis of 2 fields

Tags: awk

file1

> session=1|w,eventbase=4,operation=1,rule=15
>       session=1|e,eventbase=5,operation=2,rule=14
>       session=2|t,eventbase=,operation=1,rule=13

file2

> field1,field2,field3,session=1,fieldn,operation=1,fieldn
>       field1,field2,field3,session=1,fieldn,operation=2,fieldn
>       field1,field2,field3,session=2,fieldn,operation=2,fieldn
>       field1,field2,field3,session=2,fieldn,operation=1,fieldn

Output

> field1,field2,field3,session=1,fieldn,operation=1,fieldn,eventbase=4,rule=15
>       field1,field2,field3,session=1,fieldn,operation=2,fieldn,eventbase=5,rule=14
>       field1,field2,field3,session=2,fieldn,operation=2,fieldn,NOMATCH
>       field1,field2,field3,session=2,fieldn,operation=1,fieldn,eventbase=,rule=13

I have Tried

> BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
>       FNR == NR {
>         split($1,s,"|")
>         session=s[1];
>         a[session,$3] = session","$2","$3","$4;
>         next
>       }
>       {
>         split($4,x,"|");
>         nsession=x[1];
>         if(nsession in a)print $0 a[nsession,$6];
>         else print $0",NOMATCH";
>       }

Issue is I am not able to FIND nsession in 2D array a with if(nsession in a)
matching 2 files on the combination basis of session and operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks.. it helped.. Now I am learning :) Thanks team

> BEGIN { FS = OFS = "," }
>       FNR == NR {
>         split($1,s,"|")
>                 session=s[1];
>         a[session,$3] = session","$2","$3","$4;
>         next
>       }
>       {
>             split($4,x,"|");
>         nsession=x[1];
>         key=nsession SUBSEP $6
>         if(key in a)print $0 a[nsession,$6];
>         else print $0",NOMATCH";
>       }

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
awk -f merge.awk file1 file2
```

where `merge.awk` is

```
NR==FNR {
    sub(/[[:blank:]]*$/,"") 
    getSessionInfo(1)
    ar[ses,op]=",eventbase="evb",rule="rule
    next
}

{
    sub(/[[:blank:]]*$/,"") 
    getSessionInfo(0)
    if ((ses,op) in ar)
        print $0 ar[ses,op]
    else
        print $0 ",NOMATCH"

}

function getSessionInfo(f, a) {
    match($0,/session=([^|])[|,]/,a)
    ses=a[1]
    match($0,/operation=([^,]),/,a)
    op=a[1]
    if (f) {
        match($0,/eventbase=([^,]),/,a)
        evb=a[1]
        match($0,/rule=(.*)$/,a)
        rule=a[1]
    }
}
```